# FontAwesome Icons - cannot change css class from JavaScript in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, font-awesome

I've got the `font-awesome-ie7.min.css` in my html, however I'm unable to change the icon class dynamically using `JavaScript`/`jQuery` in **IE7**, works fine in other browsers.

```
<div id='iconDiv'>
    <i class='icon-hand-down'></i>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#iconDiv i').addClass('icon-hand-up');
    });
</script>
```

Any help! appreciated.

Comment: I am considering rolling back to glyphicons due to the same issue, I have tested with glyphicons and they do work. Still hunting for a solution.

Comment: Did you really get it to work in IE7 using glyphicons?? Because i am trying with no luck...

Answer (score 1):

Woohoo! I have a solution to this annoying issue. As with all coding that targets **IE7** this is a **complete hack** but hey, it works...

```
<div id='iconDiv'>
    <i class='icon-hand-down'></i>
    <i class='icon-hand-up hide'></i><!-- initially hidden -->
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#iconDiv i.icon-hand-down').addClass('hide');
        $('#iconDiv i.icon-hand-up').removeClass('hide');
    });
</script>
```

Put both icons into your DOM and conditionally display whichever is relevant. You get the idea. I am using this same approach for toggles in my app.

Sample CSS from [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/):

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

For reference, in my case I am using AngularJS:

```
<i data-ng-click="collapsed = !collapsed" class="icon-collapse ng-class:{'hide':collapsed}"></i>
<i data-ng-click="collapsed = !collapsed" class="icon-collapse-top ng-class:{'hide':!collapsed}"></i>
```

Comment: I was really hoping to avoid this way. But you gotta do what you gotta do.